# How to extract text in htmlnode?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

using agility, I have extracted htmlnode from specify website but i cann't retrieving data in  tag in htmlnode.InnerHtml .

```
 HtmlNode table = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='content_page']//table//*//td").FirstOrDefault;
```

How can I get these string and number?

Here is my illustration! sorry because i am limited in uploading photos.

[My image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLZNh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector as shown selects a collection of cells, and to select the first one, you would call .FirstOrDefault() (note the brackets).

And because you select a cell (not a table), you might not want to call the HtmlNode you selected "table".

So this should work:

```
HtmlNode firstCell = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='content_page']//table//*//td").FirstOrDefault();
string firstCellText = firstCell.InnerText;
```

To get to the number, you would use a different xpath that points to the second row